# Variable not initialized error?

Tags: java

Ok, so I run this code and it give me the error:

```
SammysRentalPriceWithMethods.java:49: error: variable Minutes might not have been initialized
     int TOTAL_COST = Minutes - 60 * 1 + 40;
                      ^
```

I have no idea how to fix it, also I am sorry if my code is inefficient, I have only been on Java for 3 weeks, very much a beginnner.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class SammysRentalPriceWithMethods {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       rentalTime();
       companyMotto();
       whenIGetMoney();
   }

   public static int rentalTime() { 
       int Minutes;
       Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Enter total minutes equipment was rented:");
       Minutes = inputDevice.nextInt();
       return Minutes;
   }

   public static void companyMotto() {
       System.out.println(

                       "SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS \r\n" + 
                       "S                                  S \r\n" + 
                       "S                                  S \r\n" +
                       "S                                  S \r\n" +
                       "S                                  S \r\n" +
                       "S                                  S \r\n" +
                       "S Sammy's makes it fun in the sun  S \r\n" +
                       "S                                  S \r\n" + 
                       "S                                  S \r\n" +
                       "S                                  S \r\n" +
                       "S                                  S \r\n" +
                       "S                                  S \r\n" +
                       "S                                  S \r\n" +
                       "SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS \r\n");


   }

   public static void whenIGetMoney() {
       final int HOURLY_RATE = 40;
       final int EXTRA_MIN_RATE = 1; 
       int Minutes; 

       int TOTAL_COST = Minutes - 60 * 1 + 40;
       System.out.println("You rented our equipment for " + Minutes + " minutes!");
       System.out.println("The total cost of an " + Minutes + " minute rental is $" + TOTAL_COST + ".");
   }

}
```

I get the error in my last method telling me that the varible Minutes isnt initialized, got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try this:

```
int min = rentalTime();
companyMotto();
whenIGetMoney(min);
```

with this modification:

```
public static void whenIGetMoney(int min) {
    final int HOURLY_RATE = 40;
    final int EXTRA_MIN_RATE = 1; 
    int Minutes = min;
    ...
```

Comment: I would like to let you know that, I. Love. You. This worked perfectly! dsfajfldahskflaifudsakdflh Sweet baby Jesus Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a local variable without initializing it first. Your `Minutes` variable isn't initialized and you try to use it. just declare it like `int Minutes = 0;` in the `whenIGetMoney()` method.
Anyway, the result won't be what you expect to be, as the variable `Minutes` has not the correct value in it.